# Why does dateutil.parser.parse() get the year wrong on this string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dateutil

I'm working on parsing log files, which have variable datetime formats in their timestamps. I am passing this string: `Feb 22 08:58:24 router1` to `dateutil.parser.parse()` to try and extract the timestamp, like so:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Feb 22 08:58:24 router1', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2001, 2, 22, 8, 58, 24)
```

Which results in the date: `February 22nd, 2001`

Why is the year parsed as 2001 rather than the current year, 2019?

Comment: At a gusss, `router1` is being interpreted somehow as `1` and is mapping to 2001. Do you get the same result with the `1` or `router1` removed

Comment: ok, so on my tests, `router 2` prints `2002`, same for just `2`.

Comment: Ah, it must ignore `router` because `fuzzy=True`, that's a little frustrating

Comment: It ignores the `router` but not the `1` next to it. You can check this by passing the `fuzzy_with_tokens=True` arg instead of `fuzzy=True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser is ignoring `router` but not the `1` next to it. This can be checked by passing the `fuzzy_with_tokens=True` argument. The output results in a tuple with the first item as the datetime object representation of the timestamp and the second item as the ignored strings.

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse('Feb 22 08:58:24 router1', fuzzy_with_tokens=True))
#Output:
(datetime.datetime(2001, 2, 22, 8, 58, 24), (' ', ' router'))
```